# How to incorporate gam() in xyplot() from Lattice package?

Tags: r, lattice, gam, mgcv

I am trying to incorporate generalized additive models `gam()` from `mgcv` package to either `xyplot()` function or `coplot()` function from `lattice` package in R.

The data can be found in http://statweb.stanford.edu/~tibs/ElemStatLearn/, by selecting ozone data.

Here are my code for kernel smoothing.

```
    ozonedata=ozone 
    Temperature=equal.count(ozonedata$temperature,4,1/2)
    Wind=equal.count(ozonedata$wind,4,1/2)

    xyplot(ozone^(1/3) ~ radiation | Temperature * Wind, data = ozonedata, as.table = TRUE, 
           panel = function(x, y, ...) {panel.xyplot(x, y, ...);panel.loess(x, y)}, 
           pch = 20,xlab = "Solar Radiation", ylab = "Ozone (ppb)")
```

or

```
    coplot((ozone^(1/3))~radiation|temperature*wind,data=ozonedata,number=c(4,4),
           panel = function(x, y, ...) panel.smooth(x, y, span = .8, ...),
           xlab="Solar radiation (langleys)", ylab="Ozone (cube root ppb)")
```

The generalized additive models is generated as following.

```
    gam_ozone = gam(ozone^(1/3)~s(radiation)+s(temperature)+s(wind),data=ozonedata,method="GCV.Cp")
```

Now I am having a trouble combining fitting from `gam()` into lattice plots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work. Notice that we are passing in the `gam_ozone` object as a parameter to `xyplot` called `gam`. This will allow us to access it in the panel function.

```
xyplot(ozone^(1/3) ~ radiation | Temperature * Wind, data = ozonedata, 
    as.table = TRUE, gam=gam_ozone, 
    panel = function(x, y, gam,...) {

        xx <- dimnames(trellis.last.object())
        ww <- arrayInd(packet.number(), .dim=sapply(xx, length))
        avgtmp <- mean(xx[[1]][[ww[1]]])
        avgwind <- mean(xx[[2]][[ww[2]]])

        gx<-seq(min(x, na.rm=T), max(x, na.rm=T), length.out=50)
        gy<-predict(gam, data.frame(radiation=gx, 
            temperature=avgtmp, wind=avgwind))

        panel.xyplot(x, y, ...);
        panel.xyplot(gx, gy, ..., col="red", type="l");
    }, 
    pch = 20,xlab = "Solar Radiation", ylab = "Ozone (ppb)"
)
```

Now in order to use the `gam` to predict, you're going to have to find a value to use for wind and temperature for each panel. What i've decide to do, is just take the middle value for each shingle range. So I used a [Deepayan-approved, undocumented feature](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/Accessor-functions-in-lattice-graphics-td3609435.html) to get at the ranges for each of the current shingles with the call to `dimnames`. And then i find the current panel with `packet.number()` Once I have the ranges, i take the means to get an average value.

Not i'll use the `gam` model we passed in to predict the curve for each panel. I calculate a range of 50 `x` values based on observed values and then predict from the `gam` a new line.

Finally I draw the raw data with `panel.xyplot` and then i draw the `gam` predicted line.

[image: sample lattice output with gam smooth curve]